# Get windows network logon session IP

Tags: c#, windows, security, winapi

I am writing a piece of code that queries the existing logon sessions on a windows machine. For network logons, I am trying to find the IP address and/or name of the machine from which the logon was done.

I got the list of logon sessions so far by using LsaEnumerateLogonSessions/LsaGetLogonSessionData, but the IP is nowhere to be found in the returned SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA structure.

How do I get the IP address/machine name of a network logon session?

```
DateTime systime = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

UInt64 sessionCount;
IntPtr luidPtr;
LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(out sessionCount, out luidPtr);
IntPtr iter = luidPtr;                              
for (ulong i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)            
{
    IntPtr sessionData;

    LsaGetLogonSessionData(iter, out sessionData);
    var data = 
        (SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(sessionData, typeof(SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA));

    if (data.PSiD != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(data.PSiD);

        SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE secType = (SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE)data.LogonType;
        DateTime logonTime = systime.AddTicks((long)data.LoginTime);

        string authpackage = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.AuthenticationPackage.buffer);
        string domain = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.LoginDomain.buffer);
        string username = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.Username.buffer);
        string dnsDomainName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.DnsDomainName.buffer);
        string logonServer = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.LogonServer.buffer);
        string upn = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.Upn.buffer);

        Console.WriteLine("SID "+sid+" Type: " + secType + "\t" + domain + "\\" + username + "\tTime: " + logonTime);

        if (secType == SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE.Network)
        {
            // TODO get IP/machine name
        }
    }
    iter = (IntPtr)((int)iter + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LUID)));
    LsaFreeReturnBuffer(sessionData);
}
LsaFreeReturnBuffer(luidPtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA` has a `DnsDomainName` field:

> An `LSA_UNICODE_STRING` structure that contains the DNS name for the owner of the logon session.

If you need the IP address, do a reverse DNS lookup on that name using [`gethostbyname()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524.aspx) or [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx).

Alternatively, `SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA` also has a `Session` field.  If it is not 0, you can pass it to [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx), setting the `WTSInfoClass` parameter to [`WTSClientAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383861.aspx) and the `ppBuffer` parameter to the address of a [`WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS*`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383857.aspx) pointer variable.